# boto3 EC2 script email: One email for all status checks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I am getting one email per instance that fails status checks. I want to get one email for all status checks.

Here is my code:

```
import boto3
import smtplib

client = boto3.client("ec2")
clientsns = boto3.client("sns")

status = client.describe_instance_status(IncludeAllInstances = True)
#failed_instances = []
for i in status["InstanceStatuses"]:
#        failed_instances.append(i[{'Instance'})]      
        in_status = i['InstanceStatus']['Details'][0]['Status']
        sys_status = i['SystemStatus']['Details'][0]['Status']
        
        # check statuses failed instances
        if ((in_status != 'passed') or (sys_status != 'passed')):
             msg = f'The following instances failed status checks, {i["InstanceId"]}'
             clientsns.publish(TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:462518063038:test',Message=msg)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
import boto3
import botocore
from boto3 import Session

boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='account2')

def get_tag(tags, key='Name'):
    if not tags: return ''
    for tag in tags:
        if tag['Key'] == key:
            return tag['Value']
    return ''

client = boto3.client("ec2")
conn = boto3.resource('ec2')
#instances = conn.instances.filter()
instances = conn.instances.filter(
        Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])

filter_for = {
    "running": [{"Name": "instance-state-name", "Values": ["running"]}],
}

ec2instance = client.describe_instance_status(IncludeAllInstances = True, Filters=filter_for["running"])

failed_instances = []
for i in ec2instance["InstanceStatuses"]:    
        in_status = i['InstanceStatus']['Details'][0]['Status']
        sys_status = i['SystemStatus']['Details'][0]['Status']
        
        # check statuses failed instances
        if ((in_status != 'passed') or (sys_status != 'passed')):
             failed_instances.append(i["InstanceId"])

if len(failed_instances)>0:
 #   new_line = '\n'
 #   msg = f'The following instances failed status checks:{new_line} {new_line.join(failed_instances)}'
 #   #msg = f'The following instances failed status checks, {failed_instances}'
 
 #   clientsns.publish(TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:462518063038:test',Message=msg)

for j in failed_instances:
  instance = [x for x in list(instances) if x.id == j][0]
  instance_name = get_tag(instance.tags)        
  print (instance_name, instance.id, instance.instance_type)
```

Comment: Thank you. how do I put  each instance on different line

Comment: Just use the new line character `\n`. See edited answer

Comment: Hi any idea how i can print out the TAG name of the instance. The key value in the tag is Name and value

Comment: See the edited answer. Also, there are other questions in SO with more details.

Comment: does it mean I need double for loop? I want to print out the instance name, Instance ID for failed status check